# How to keep image from appearing again (css animation)

Tags: css, animation

I have 2 clouds (=wolkje) that float by in my animation. However I want these clouds to float by 1 time during the animation and not repeatedly.

.wolkje1{

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
width: 650px;
height: 120px;
top: 3px;
background-size: 110px;
background-image: url(../images/wolkje.png);
animation: wolk 10s infinite linear;
```

}
.wolkje2{

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
width: 650px;
height: 120px;
top: 190px;
background-size: 110px;
background-image: url(../images/wolkje.png);
animation: wolk 15s infinite linear normal;
```

}
@keyframes wolk {

```
0% {background-position-x: -100px ;}
100% {background-position-x: 1000px}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ìnfinite` from

`animation: wolk 10s infinite linear;`

It will prevent your animation from looping

Answer (score 1):

remove infinite from

```
animation: wolk 10s infinite linear;
```

use it as -

```
animation: wolk 10s linear;
```